# How can I set my application to run on the High performance GPU by default?

Tags: c#, gpu, nsis

Nowadays a good deal of laptops come with 2 GPUs - a high-performance one and a power-saving one (less powerful). Most of the application, which I use on my laptop run with my integrated(power-saving) GPU, but still some of them are set to open with the high-performance card. I am trying to config the app which I am building to run on the high performance GPU by default, but I can't find any information about the topic anywhere. I hope that someone can shed a bit of light onto this. I will distribute my application with an NSIS installer and I guess that I'll have to add the path of my application to a list of applications for NVidia/ATI cards. The application is programmed in C#. Also, does anyone know how things stand with desktop PCs? What happens if a PC has 2 GPUs and I have to choose the more powerful one?

Milcho

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not something you have any control over.  The laptop's OS's kernel decides whether it needs to switch over.